# Explode() String Breaking Array Into Too Many Elements

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I am working on scraping and then parsing an HTML string to get the two URL parameters inside the href. After scraping the element I need, $description, the full string ready for parsing is:

```
<a target="_blank" href="CoverSheet.aspx?ItemID=18833&amp;MeetingID=773">Description</a><br>
```

Below I use the explode parameter to split the $description variable string based on the = delimiter. I then further explode based on the double quote delimiter.

Problem I need to solve: I want to only print the numbers for MeetingID parameter before the double quote, "773".

```
<?php
echo "Description is: " . htmlentities($description); // prints the string referenced above
$htarray = explode('=', $description); // explode the $description string which includes the link. ... then, find out where the MeetingID is located
echo $htarray[4] .  "<br>"; // this will print the string which includes the meeting ID: "773">Description</a><br>"

$meetingID = $htarray[4];
echo "Meeting ID is " . substr($meetingID,0,3); 
?>
```

The above echo statement using substr works to print the meeting ID, 773.

However, I want to make this bulletproof in the event MeetingID parameter exceeds 999, then we would need 4 characters. So that's why I want to delimit it by the double quotes, so it prints all numbers before the double quotes.

I try below to isolate all of the amount before the double quotes... but it isn't seeming to work correctly yet.

```
<?php
 $htarray = explode('"', $meetingID); // split the $meetingID string based on the " delimiter
 echo "Meeting ID0 is " . $meetingID[0] ; // this prints just the first number, 7
 echo "Meeting ID1 is " . $meetingID[1] ; // this prints just the second number, 7
 echo "Meeting ID2 is " . $meetingID[2] ; // this prints just the third number, 3

?>
```

Question, why is the array $meetingID[0] not printing the THREE numbers before the delimiter, ", but rather just printing a single number? If the explode function works properly, shouldn't it be splitting the string referenced above based on the double quotes, into just two elements? The string is

```
"773">Description</a><br>"
```

So I can't understand why when echoing after the explode with double quote delimiter, it's only printing one number at a time..

Comment: "why is the array $meetingID[0] not printing the THREE numbers before the delimiter" -- because `$meetingID` is the string. The exploded arary is `$htarray`. I think you're looking for `$htarray[0]`?

Comment: you are right! Thank you, problem solved.

Comment: if you can write that as an answer I can give you the correct response.

Comment: You would normally be better off processing HTML with something like DOMDocument, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php.

Comment: @NigelRen thanks I am using the PHP Simple Dom Parser but trying to get more advanced once I have the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting the wrong response is because you're using the wrong variable.

```
$htarray = explode('"', $meetingID);

echo "Meeting ID0 is " . $meetingID[0] ; // this prints just the first number, 7
echo "Meeting ID1 is " . $meetingID[1] ; // this prints just the second number, 7
echo "Meeting ID2 is " . $meetingID[2] ; // this prints just the third number, 3

echo "Meeting ID is " . $htarray[0] ; // this prints 773
```

There's an easier way to do this though, using regular expressions:

```
$description = '<a target="_blank" href="CoverSheet.aspx?ItemID=18833&amp;MeetingID=773">Description</a><br>';

$meetingID = "Not found";
if (preg_match('/MeetingID=([0-9]+)/', $description, $matches)) {
    $meetingID = $matches[1];
}

echo "Meeting ID is " . $meetingID;
// this prints 773 or Not found if $description does not contain a (numeric) MeetingID value
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a very easy way to do it:

Your Str:

```
$str ='<a target="_blank" href="CoverSheet.aspx?ItemID=18833&amp;MeetingID=773">Description</a><br>';
```

Make substr:

```
$params = substr( $str, strpos( $str, 'ItemID'), strpos( $str, '">') - strpos( $str, 'ItemID') );
```

You will get substr like this :

```
ItemID=18833&MeetingID=773
```

Now do whatever you want to do!